# media queries color monochrome and printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, printing, media-queries

I am trying to set up some alternative styles for monochrome devices - i.e. black & white print outs.

I thought I could just use a simple css media query to do this but it's not working.

```
.Something { color: red; }
@media all and (monochrome) 
{
  .Something { color: black; }
}
```

When I try to print (or preview) it the monochrome styles are not applied.

The above is a poor example but I set up a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qC3af/

When viewing a print preview of the above in firefox neither color nor monochrome is applied.
In chrome it keeps the color feature even when in black & white mode.

What am I missing?

I did notice that JSFiddle has highlighted color differently from all the other media queries. Is that a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is unreliable. You can see descriptions here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/mediaqueries/color.html

I will note that my nook believes it has at least 16 but not 32 color-indexes so it seems aware of it's 16 shades, but then it mismarks them and fails the monochrome test...

Really a browser can't be entirely aware of its display(s.) For example, it may be displaying to a virtual device that has more capabilities than the real hardware.

Comment: so basically what you are saying is the color and monochrome media queries are (at time of writing) essentially worthless?

That's a shame.
I guess I'll leave my css changes in but un-tested on the off-chance that they will one day be properly supported.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is nice to ask the device for an intial default, but if you take it seriously with no user override, you may do more harm than good..

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I usually use `@media print` for my printing operations. Inside the media print you can set `@page`

For instance, say you want to print the page on landscape mode. This just works perfectly.

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: landscape;
    }
}
```

For your question, I would use `@media print`. Inside the body selector you can use `filter: grayscale(100%);`

So the code would look like this.

```
 @media print {
        body {
            filter: grayscale(100%);
        }
    }
```

if you target older IE you should add `filter: Gray();` for Safari and Opera  `filter: url('#grayscale');`

Here is the final code...

```
@media print {
  body {
    /* IE4-8 and 9 */
    filter: Gray();
    /* SVG version for IE10, Chrome 17, FF3.5, Safari 5.2 and Opera 11.6 */
    filter: url('#grayscale'); 
    /* CSS3 filter, at the moment Webkit only. Prefix it for future implementations */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* future-proof */
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood this 5year old question

Comment: Just gave an answer in case someone may get benefit from it mate :)